# How to set width 100% of input tag

Tags: html, css

I have input tag beside him i have little icon, ,now i wan't to set for input tag width 100%, and on different screens to be fit to display, but i can't i tried using css tricks **calc**

width:calc(100%-100px) !important;

http://jsfiddle.net/p0s8yad7/

HTML

```
<div class="one-row-location">
        <label class="item item-input location-input">

          <input  class="input-label inputlocation" type="text" name="geolocation" id="geolocation" placeholder="Lokation" value="">
        </label><div class="location-icon">
    <img src="http://oi62.tinypic.com/10ng7b5.jpg">
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.one-row-location{
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.item-input{
    padding:0;
    background-color:#fff ! important;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;

  ! important;

}

.item-input .input-label{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#99999f;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style: italic;

}
.input-label{
    padding-right: 4px ! important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
        width:calc(100%-100px) !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to position the icon inside the input tag?

Comment: not working, i put div tag inside label, i think you understand me , i want t oset for only screen to be input tag width 100%-icon width px

Comment: To start, the "! important" around line 13 of you pasted code is not valid. If you were trying to apply that to the margin-right rule, it must come before the semi-colon. I would recommend researching "putting icon inside input" to find a solid solution.

Comment: So do you want the icon inside text field or left side to it? along with 100% width of text field

Comment: i wont on RIGHT side, alogn with 100% width of text field

Comment: Do you want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p0s8yad7/4/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what author asks for:
http://jsfiddle.net/p0s8yad7/3/

HTML

```
<div class="one-row-location">
<div class="location-icon"><img src="http://oi62.tinypic.com/10ng7b5.jpg"></div>
      <div class="location-field"><input  class="input-label inputlocation" type="text" name="geolocation" id="geolocation" placeholder="Lokation" value="" />
    </div>
```

And CSS

```
    .one-row-location {
  width: 80%;  // For demonstartion purposes - this width can be whatever is needed
  display: table;
}
.location-field{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.inputlocation{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#99999f;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style: italic;
    height:27px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.location-icon {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 29px;
    height:33px;
}
```

Comment: can you explain me, when is neccessary to use display:table; and display:table-cell;

Comment: `display: table` and `display: table-cell` makes div's inside container to behave like HTML table cells, which means - expand to fill all available remaining space. Since one of the divs (icon container) have width defined, it won't expand, while other one do not have width defined, so it fills remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap your label around your input.  Then put the input and the img inside of a div and add float left to the img and float right to the input.

```
<div class="one-row-location">
<label class="item item-input location-input"></label>
<div>
    <input  class="input-label inputlocation" type="text" name="geolocation" id="geolocation" placeholder="Lokation" value="">
    <img class="location-icon" src="http://oi62.tinypic.com/10ng7b5.jpg">
</div>
```

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/1vhhL6p0/